# Titanium Alloy - Create view without controller and access components inside that view

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I have a Titanium Alloy view called `overlay.xml` that doesn't have a controller. I am creating it in another controller called `episode.js` and adding it to a container in `episode.xml`. I'm doing this in order to make `overlay.xml` into reusable view that can be added anywhere.

For example

**episode.js**

```
// create the overlay view
var overlay = Alloy.createController("overlay").getView();
// add it somewhere in episode.xml
$.episodeImage.add(overlay);
```

Inside `overlay.xml` I have several components, like buttons and labels, that I'd like to access in `Episode View` to add event listeners to. For example:

**overlay.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <View id="overlay">
        <Button id="theButton" title="Click Me!" />
        <Label id="theLabel" text="I am a label" />
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

And then in **episode.js** for example:

```
var overlay = Alloy.createController("overlay").getView();
$.episodeImage.add(overlay);

// EXAMPLE: Get the button from overlay.xml and add an event listener
$.theButtonFromOverlayXML.addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert("You clicked the button from overlay.xml!"):
});
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can access views through their ids in another controller. The only need to assign controller object and view object to two different variables:

**episode.js**

```
var overlay = Alloy.createController("overlay");

overlay.theButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('You clicked the button from overlay.xml!');
});

var overlayView = overlay.getView();
$.episodeImage.add(overlayView);
// shorter version
$.episodeImage.add( overlay.getView() );
```

Comment: Great thanks daniula, exactly what I am looking for. Though I feel a little bit uncomfortable that it is not accessible via view but controller.

Answer (score 0):

The objects are exposed on the controller object by ID. Get them there before you `overlay.getView()`.

But if all you want is click listeners, why not add the listener to overlay, then check if the source is what you want clicked? That would keep the internal state of the view abstracted from the consuming view.

```
overlay.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (evt.source.id === 'theButton') {
        alert('You clicked the button from overlay.xml!');
    }
});
```